# Make JavaScript work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, validation

I have this JavaScript that works well in both Safari and FireFox, but in IE it doesn't work and i can't make it work! Google ain't helping a lot here :(
The script changes content in a div dependend on what link is clicked in a little menu!
I have the code on this page and on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtpEL/5/)!

The page where the code should/would work: [Live workingpage](http://simonhollander.dk/v/churchill.shtml)

Hope you guys will help me make this work in IE. It works in Safari and sometimes in FF.

**QUESTION UPDATED**

Here's my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
$(function() {
$('#om').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('heste/Churchill/html/churchilltekst.html');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#resul').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('heste/Churchill/html/churchillresul.html');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#billeder').click(function(e){
    $('.hestetekst').load('heste/Churchill/html/churchillbilleder.html');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#video').click(function(e){
    $('.hestetekst').load('heste/Churchill/html/churchillvideo.html');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#afkom').click(function(e){
    $('.hestetekst').load('heste/Churchill/html/churchillafkom.html');
    e.preventDefault();
});
});

$.ajaxSetup({
'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
}
}); 
//  End -->
</script>
```

The HTML including the menu:

```
<div class="hesteundertop">
    <p>
        <span class="linkstyle3"><a id="om" href="#">Om Churchill</a></span> &#124; 
        <span class="linkstyle3"><a id="resul" href="#">Resultater</a></span> &#124;
        <span class="linkstyle3"><a id="billeder" href="#">Billeder</a></span> &#124;         
        <span class="linkstyle3"><a id="video" href="#">Video</a></span> &#124;
        <span class="linkstyle3"><a id="afkom" href="#">Afkom</a></span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="hestetekst">
    <!--#include virtual="heste/Churchill/html/churchilltekst.html"-->
</div>
```

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: And is it reporting any errors? Either the infamous yellow flag, or (if you're using IE8 or later) in the "F12 Developer's Tools".

Comment: What is the problem in IE?  "Doesn't work" is not much of a description.  Did you look in the error console to see what it reports?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder > I'm using IE 11. I've tried with the tool, sry for missing it in topic, but it only says: "JavaScript Console is attached and accepting commands." But the script still doesn't work...

Comment: hey can you update your fiddle with live url so that we can see the page when we click links

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh > Working on it to make it work ;)

Comment: NEW FIDDLE: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vtpEL/5/)
I can't update the question yet. But i have updated with live links.

Comment: AND THE REAL PAGE [HERE](http://www.simonhollander.dk/v/churchill.shtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page source, it seems that the page has been minimised badly. The entire JavaScript is a one line comment since it starts with `<!-- Begin$(function()`. The script is never executed.

By manually typing

```
$('#om').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('http://www.simonhollander.dk/v/heste/Churchill/html/churchilltekst.html');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

into the Console in Chrome, the handler is added as expected.

Comment: Thx for this answer. I have inserted a space between "Begin" and "$(function()" but this still haven't made it work.

Comment: Remove the comment part entirely. It's not the space. The whole line is a comment and therefore never executed. You do not need the `<!-- Begin` or `// End -->` parts

Comment: I really thought that these didn't matter at all?!

But this made it work! But not without removing the comma as @jfriend00 came with.

Comment: They matter in this case because the page has been minimised to **one line**. The whole page is just one line so the comments end up wrapping all of the JavaScript, effectively stopping it from running.

Comment: Okey! i didn't know that. How can i stop my pages being minimised?

Comment: Assuming your source is not all on one line, it is probably a setting on the web server. Do you have control of the web server software? If so try searching for an option similar to "compression", "optimisation" or "minimize"

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is the only issue, but you should remove the extra comma here which is known to cause issues in some versions of IE:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    },     // <== remove the comma on this line
});
```

---

Another issue.  You have two `<body>` tags in your real HTML page.

---

Another issue.  Chrome reports this when I click on a couple of your links:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.simonhollander.dk/v/heste/Churchill/html/churchillresul.html.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://simonhollander.dk' is therefore not allowed
>   access. churchill.shtml:1

Basically your ajax call is being denied for a security reason and it looks like this issue is that your page is http://simonhollander.dk, but the URL you are requesting is http://www.simonhollander.dk.  Note that one has the www. and the other does not.  This makes them different domains so ajax is blocked due to the same-origin policy.  Make the domains match exactly and this request should not be blocked.

Comment: Good spot, but IE8 and above are fine with the dangling comma in object initialisers (it's only IE7 and earlier that have the issue), and the OP has (finally) come back and said he's using IE11.

Comment: Thx, but it wasn't the problem!

Comment: @SimonJensen - well it was a problem in older versions of IE.  Perhaps if you described more about what you observe the problem to be, we could have a better chance at helping.

Comment: @jfriend00 > Hmm... I have this menu, "Om Churchill" | "Resultater" | ect. And when one of these are clicked upon, the content in the div with the class "hestetekst" should change to another content. This is not what it does, it doesn't change at all. It works perfectly in Safari, but not IE and sometimes not in FF(testing browser)...

Comment: @SimonJensen - it isn't working for me in Chrome either and the reason it isn't working is because the click event handlers are not getting installed.  My debugger is breaking on and complaining about that extra comma in the real HTML page so that's the first roadblock that is in the way. You should also see the note in my answer about two `<body>` tags.

Comment: Just updated the [real page](http://simonhollander.dk/v/churchill.shtml).

That's really weird with them two <body> tags?! My FF (looking at html-sourcecode) and HTML-program says there's only 1 <body>-tag...

Comment: @SimonJensen - now I see an ajax access control issue (exact text added to my answer).

Comment: Thx. I have now removed the entire site to it's [own domain](http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk).

The access control issue should have been fixed now! :)